# Pass parameter to $q.all callback

Tags: angularjs, q

I need to pass some local parameter to the $q.all callback

```
var actions = [];
var jsonFiles = ["a.json","b.json","c.json"];

for(var index=0; index<3; index++){
    actions.push($http.get('content/' + jsonFiles[index]);
}

$q.all(actions).then(function (values) {
    console.log(index) // Need to print current request index
}
```

current output is of course 3,3,3
I need to print 0,1,2 according to the response order (it can be 1,0,2 or other combination)

I've created a jsfiddle with my issue - http://jsfiddle.net/dorcohen/n30er4ap/

Comment: `values` is an array  , and each entry in that array is the actual index of action. so ......?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I need to access the request index, not the responses index

Comment: IMHO The request index and the response index (in values) are the same. This is provided by `$q.all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly , you should use `params` :

```
  for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) 
   {
    actions.push($http.get( jsonFiles[index], {params:{"idx": index }}));
   }
```

Then :

```
   $q.all(actions).then(function(values) {
     for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
       $scope.indexes.push(values[i].config.params.idx); 
    })
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n30er4ap/1/)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it is rather overkill, but it will work I think

```
for(var index=0; index<3; index++){
    actions.push($q.all([
       $q.resolve(index),
       $http.get('content/' + jsonFiles[index]);
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While @Royi's answer is correct, if will not work for "non-http" promises.

A nice workaround which will work for kind of promises is by using the [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) of creating a `defered` object as a wrapper and resolving your own custom object.

While this is a anti-pattern, there are some cases you want to use it like here.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button ng-click="do()">
      Click
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http, $q) {
  $scope.do = function() {
    var acts = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var defer = $q.defer(); // create your own deferred object

     // worked with a dummy promise - you can use what ever promise you want
      var promise = $q.when({
        obj: i
      });


      promise.then(
        // closure for the current deferred obj + index since we are in a loop
        function(d,idx) {
          return function(item) {
            d.resolve({res: item, index:idx}); // resolve my deferred object when I want and create a complex object with the index and the "real response"
          }
        }(defer,i));

      acts.push(defer.promise);
    }
    $q.all(acts).then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t4xp9n91/).

Comment: It will work for non-http promises. You need to resolve your promise like this:

deferred.resolve({"someObjectName": someObject});